# Make HTML Input's first character non editable - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, append

I have an Input field

```
<input type="text" value="$">
```

I need to have `$` symbol fixed in the first place of input irrespective of the number or character entered inside the input

Currently i'm appending `$` symbol externally in `onChange` function

```
value = '$' + value
```

Basically, user should not be able to clear `$` symbol. It should be fixed. How to achieve this?

I'm using javascript and React.

Comment: You might want to try using CSS to make it appear that the "$" symbol is a part of the input by making the border around both of them.  The appearance of the $ symbol is what you are after, not the functionality of the input.

Comment: So what's wrong with using the `onChange` approach??

Answer (score 3):

On input change, you can first remove all occurrences of `$` from the value. Then prefix the value with `$`.

Try the following:

```js
function inputValue(el){
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[$+]/g, ''); //replace all $ with empty string
  el.value = '$' + el.value; //prepend $ to the input value
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="$" oninput="inputValue(this)">
```

If you want to allow only numbers and dot(`.`) simply use:

```
el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your input field inside a `div`. This `div` shows a placeholder for your input field and makes it look like there is actually a `$` symbol inside, that is not editable.

```css
.foo {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.placeholder
{
    position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder" data-placeholder="$">
    <input type="text" class="foo" value="">
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].value)">
  Get Value
</button>
```